# upgrade enterprisedb postgresl version

Tags: postgresql, enterprisedb

I installed EnterpriseDB postgresql version 9.3.12 on a CentOS Server by using the following steps.

./postgresql-9.3.12-1-linux-x64.run

I now need to upgrade my postgresql to version 9.6. How can I do that? I know how to install a fresh enterprisedb postgresql instance. However, how do I upgrade an existing enterprisedb postgresql instance? Just looking for upgrade steps / documentation. Do I just start with ./postgresql-9.3.12-1-linux-x64.run and use pg_upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Install 9.6 with  installer `postgresql-9.6.*.run` , and after, then execute the `pg_upgrade` from 9.6 binaries folder with the respective options for example:

First check

```
/path_96/bin/pg_upgrade -B ... -b ... -D ... -d ... --check
```

-b the old PostgreSQL executable directory

-B the new PostgreSQL executable directory

-d the old database cluster configuration directory

-D the new database cluster configuration directory

Is all OK = Cluster Compatible run `pg_upgrade`

```
/path_96/bin/pg_upgrade -B ... -b ... -D ... -d ...
```

yo can verify if you need more options

```
pg_upgrade --help
```

Comment: You can also consider using platform-native package. like https://yum.postgresql.org/ or https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/